# How does hibernate handle collisions?

Tags: java, hibernate

I hope someone can clarify the below scenerio for me.

From what I understand, when you request a 'row' from hibernate, for example:

```
User user = UserDao.get(1);
```

I know have the user with id=1 in memory.

In a web application, if 2 web pages request and load the user at the same time, and then both update a property on the user's object, what will happend? e.g.:

```
user.pageViews += 1; // the value is current 10 before the increment
UserDao.update(user);
```

**Will this use the value that is in-memory (both requests have the value 10), or will it use the value in the database?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use two hibernate sessions for the two users. This means there are two instances of the object in the memory. If you use only one hibernate session (and so one instance of the object in memory), then the result is unpredictable.

In the case of a concurrent update the second update wins. The value of the first update is overwritten by the second update. To avoid the loss of the first update you normally use a version column (see the hibernate doc), and the second update then gets an error which you can catch and react on it (for example with an error message "Your record was modified in meantime. Please reload." which allows the second user to redo his modification on the modified record, to ensure his modif does not get lost.

in the case of a page view counter, like in your example, as a different solution you could write a synchronized methods which counts the page views sequentially.

Answer (score 1):

By default the `in memory` value is used for the update.

In the following I assume you want to implement an automatic page view counter, not to modify the `User` in a web user interface. If you want this take a look at **Hibernate optimistic locking**.

So, supposing you need 100% accuracy when counting the page views, you can lock your `User` entity while you modify their `pageView` value to obtain exclusivity on the table row:

```
Session session = ...
Transaction tx = ...

session.lock(user, LockMode.UPGRADE);
user.increasePageViews();

tx.commit();
session.close();
```

The `LockMode.UPGRADE` will translate in a `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` in your database so be careful to maintain the lock as little as possible to not impact application scalability.